# Gitlab Pages on EC2 returns 502 error with "tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, gitlab

I have deployed a Gitlab instance on EC2 (version 16.4.0) running on Amazon Linux 2 AMI.
Following the Gitlab documentation, I installed Let'sencrypt certificates for my Gitlab NGINX server as well as Gitlab Pages NGINX server like so:

```yaml
## GitLab URL
external_url "https://gitlab-test.tools.myhostname.io"

# NGINX configuration
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab-test.tools.myhostname.io.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab-test.tools.myhostname.io.key"

# Letsencrypt configuration
letsencrypt['enable'] = true
letsencrypt['auto_renew_hour'] = "12"
letsencrypt['auto_renew_minute'] = "30" # Renew every 1th day of the month at 12:30
letsencrypt['auto_renew_day_of_month'] = "*/1"

## GitLab Pages
pages_external_url "https://gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io"
pages_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io.crt"
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io.key"
```

Using the Gitlab web console is fine, but when I try to display a Pages website, I get a 502 error - *Whoops, something went wrong on our end*.

[image]

Strangely though, the HTTPS certificate of the error page correctly displays the correct Let'sencrypt certificate, with valid dates. No HTTPS error on the browser side.

The error messages appears like this in the pages nginx logs:

```json
{"correlation_id":"01HDECSGCCFK5SKZZA206X6MAJ",
"error":"Get \"https://gitlab-test.tools.myhostname.io/api/v4/internal/pages?host=poc.gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority",
"host":"poc.gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io",
"level":"error",
"msg":"could not fetch domain information from a source","path":"/favicon.ico",
"time":"2023-10-23T13:50:04Z"}
```

I tried renewing certificates using the following commands

```bash
# Main certificate
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email certificats@myhostname.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d gitlab-test.tools.myhostname.io

# Pages certificate
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email certificats@myhostname.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d '*.gitlab-test-pages.myhostname.io'
```

Comment: Where is it that you're seeing the error message in your title?

Comment: It's in the nginx logs. I edited the question to add the logs.